# Javascript variable not set in array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I run this in javascript, I want to set incremental values:

```
var parts = {};
var parts_default = {success: function(){}, dane: "cos tam"};
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   parts[i] = parts_default ;
   parts[i].varX = i ;
}
console.log(parts);
```

I got result:

```
{
 "1": {
    "dane": "cos tam",
    "varX": 3
  },
  "2": {
    "dane": "cos tam",
    "varX": 3
  },
  "3": {
    "dane": "cos tam",
    "varX": 3
  }
}
```

variable varX has the same value 3, but I expected below:

```
{
 "1": {
    "dane": "cos tam",
    "varX": 1
  },
  "2": {
    "dane": "cos tam",
    "varX": 2
  },
  "3": {
    "dane": "cos tam",
    "varX": 3
  }
}
```

What's wrong with that?

Comment: `parts[i] = parts_default`, you are setting the same object to all of the properties. meaning `parts[1] === parts[2] && parts[2] === parts[3]`, so you are modifying the same object when you use `parts[i].varX`

Comment: Objects are passed by reference so each is just a pointer to the same object in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the **same** object to `parts` each time in the loop, because when you do:

```
parts[i] = parts_default;
```

that copies the object reference, not the object. Then when you do

```
parts[i].varX = i;
```

you're updating that single object.

You can copy the object with the new `Object.assign` function, which can be polyfilled for older JavaScript engines:

```js
var parts = {};
var parts_default = {success: function(){}, dane: "cos tam"};
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   parts[i] = Object.assign({}, parts_default);
   parts[i].varX = i ;
}
console.log(parts);
```

Note that all of the objects will share the same `success` function.

Comment: I did same in my first approach but why does output shows `**ref:3**` for last 2 objects. Should this not create different objects every time?

Comment: @Rajesh: It does. But it's a shallow copy. As I said above, the same `success` function is shared by all copies. (Which is likely to be fine.) That's what the `ref:` thing is about.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for creating a new object.

> The `Object.create()` method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.

```js
var parts = {};
var parts_default = { success: function() {}, dane: "cos tam" };
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   parts[i] = Object.create(parts_default);
   parts[i].varX = i;
}

console.log(parts);
```